# How are the honorific forms of the verb 이다 created?

Tags: verb, verb-endings, honorific

From what I understood, for the present tense there are the following forms that can be used depending on the situation. Here I've made some examples of these with the verb 하다 and I've written the ones that I know for the verb 이다, what are the ones missing?

1. Informal: 해 | 야/이야
2. Honorific informal:하셔 | ?
3. Semi-formal:해요 | 예요/이에요
4. Honorific semi-formal:하세요 | ?
5. Formal:합니다 | ㅂ니다/입니다
6. Honorific formal:하십니다 | ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- ⑵ “(something without a final)-(이)셔” / “(something with a final)-이셔”

  - “저분이 네 아버지**셔**?”
  - “저분은 여기 오는 유일한 손님**이셔**.”
- ⑷ “(something without a final)-(이)세요” / “(something with a final)-이세요”

  - “혹시 사업가**세요**?”
  - “갑자기 웬일**이세요**?”
- ⑹ “(something without a final)-(이)십니다” / “(something with a final)-이십니다”

  - Similarly….

By a “final,” I mean a “받침 (final consonant).” “(이)” is usually omitted if possible.

Comment: Thank you so much, what about the honorific forms of 아니다?

Comment: @EmaTavox “아니셔,” “아니세요,” “아니십니다.” (e.g. “저분은 제가 아는 분이 아니십니다.”)